# Getting Error: No such module 'Alamofire' while using the Alamofire.playground

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using xCode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

I just downloaded the Alamofire repo from github and build the Alamofire project. I was able to run the iOS example included in the workspace without any problems.

However, when I try to use the included playground to test out some calls, I get the "No such module" error. I have tried the steps outlined at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportingaFrameworkIntoaPlayground.html but that still did not seem to help.

Can you tell me what needs to be done to make the playground work with the Alamofire framework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to build the Alamofire framework project and ensure that the workspace settings were set Xcode defaults for the Build Locaiton.